# Rails: group and count sql query include zero's

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm able to run this query to generate a hash of Regions and group by answer (including zero count):

`Region.includes(:answers).group("regions.region").count("answers")`

produces:

```
{"blar"=>0, "East"=>0, "East Midlands"=>11, "London"=>8, "North East"=>0, "North West"=>0, "Northern Ireland"=>0, "Rest of World"=>89, "Scotland"=>0, "South East"=>0, "South West"=>0, "Wales"=>0, "West Midlands"=>0, "Yorkshire and the Humber"=>0}
```

However when I want this result (to include count zeros) for a particular question, it only displays a hash of the regions with an answer.

Query:

```
Region.includes(:answers).where("answers.question_id = 14").group("regions.region").count("answers")
```

produces:

```
{"East Midlands"=>3, "London"=>1, "Rest of World"=>4}
```

I understand the query will be selecting only answers for question_id, so this gives the given output but I've tried many different queries (including LEFT OUT JOINS) and been unable to get the desired result.

For reference:

Region has_many :answers

Answer belongs_to :region

Answer belongs_to :question

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I was able to solve this by adding the sql IS NULL OR to the where clause as so:

```
Region.includes(:answers).where("answers.id IS NULL OR answers.question_id = 14").group("regions.region").count("answers")
```

Producing:

```
{"blar"=>0, "East"=>0, "East Midlands"=>1, "London"=>0, "North East"=>0, "North West"=>0, "Northern Ireland"=>0, "Rest of World"=>4, "Scotland"=>0, "South East"=>0, "South West"=>0, "Wales"=>0, "West Midlands"=>0, "Yorkshire and the Humber"=>0}
```

Probably not the best way but it did the job

Answer (score 0):

Add SELECT with NULLs explicit, like following:

```
Region.outer_joins(:answers).select('region.name IS NULL').
```

Comment: The result is the same if I include this select method